# Why does this code lead to Compile Error?

Tags: c++, algorithm, compilation

I have exam papers that were from last year and I have been reviewing it. I have a problem one point. As you can see the codes below, my teacher said the given codes will be lead compile error, but I tried it on Visual Studio on my computer and it worked with the outputs : 4.0 The codes are:

```
float x = 3.0;
float y = 2.0;
int j = 10;
int k = 4;                 

j = j / k + y;
```

I will attend the exam tomorrow about it. What should I write as an answer?

Comment: C++ or C? They are different languages. Pick one.

Comment: I see a potential logic error, but I'm at a loss for a compiler error.

Comment: If warnings are treated as errors, `x` being unused may be causing an error. Edit : Is this in a function or just at the file scope level? If this is your entire source file then that may be the error being asked about. `j = j / k + y;` needs to be in a function.

Comment: The result of thw second line is a `float`. You can't convert implicitly a `float` to `int`.

Comment: @CoderCharmander Yes, you can.

Comment: Another note: If your  output is the value of `j` then it cannot possibly be `4.0`. It should be `4` since `j` is an `integer` type.

Comment: Well, it may seem obvious, but it doesn't have a main() function, so it certainly won't compile on its own. If it's in a function body however, it should work, except for what was already said.
And maybe make a note about operator precedence in ```j / k + y```, which kinda looks like it wants to be ```j / (k+y)```

Comment: @a.Gurlyeno Did your teacher pass the exam already?")

Comment: Please show the verbatim code that works on your computer. The code snippet you posted doesn't do anything. It won't even compile. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: it is in the main function of course. also its in c++

Answer (score 3):

There's only two issues I see here:

- The `x` variable is unused, which *could* be an error if your compiler is set to enable warnings on unused variables, and you have asked your compiler to turn all warnings into errors.  However, it will generally compile fine with default compiler settings.
- The assignment statement stores a `float` value in an `int` variable, which is probably what your teacher is getting at. However, this conversion is automatic and does not cause an error (but may generate a warning).

In other words, your teacher appears to be wrong about this and hasn't actually tried compiling this code.

---

As others have stated, "the code needs to be wrapped in an `int main()` function" is also a pretty bulletproof way to get the question right if your teacher is reasonable.

---

If you get marked wrong for stating that there is no compile-time error, go talk to the teacher and show them.  I've successfully argued back points on exams for similar reasons.  (I had one question asking why `o.ToString;` was a compile-time error in a C# program.  The professor was looking for "missing parens."  The correct answer was "`o` is not in scope.")

Comment: thank you. also yeah the compiler worked but generated warning

Answer (score 2):

```
int main() {
  float x = 3.f; // unused-variable warning
  float y = 2.f;
  int j = 10;
  int k = 4;

  j = j / k + y;
}
```

Will compile with g++, if you compile with

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -pedantic-errors test.cpp
```

You will only have a warning because `x` is not used.

Comment: It [also warns about `void main()`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/HKmcXh).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with him pointing out another warning you didn't mention, when that's all we're talking about.

Comment: @MarkStorer I'm not agree, I'm trying to help people and I took my time to do it. and yes you can leave a comment but downvote means that my answer was incorrect.

Comment: Fix the "void" bug ^^.

Comment: then sorry about that

Comment: Downvotes don't necessarily mean incorrect answer. They officially mean "Not useful". An answer might be not useful because it's wrong. But it could be right and take a poor or dangerous path to the answer. There are too many reasons someone might downvote to list. Ultimately someone decided the answer wasn't useful. Could be they voted before the `void main` was corrected and will come back when they want the rep they burned on the downvote back. And maybe not.